# Rewriting date-based URL:s with .htaccess - solution?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been able to set up proper permalink redirections in Wordpress by entering `/%category%/%postname%/` and using the below shown snippet as my .htacccess file. - Working great!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However when trying to access links to archived posts, such as "December 2010" (shown in the sidebar), I get to this page: `http://localhost/subfolder/2010/10/`

How can I instead rewrite all date-based requests to the following page? `http://localhost/subfolder/archive/2010/10/`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad this prior to your last rule:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/\d{4}/\d{2}

then add a new rule e.g.

RewriteRule subfolder/(\d{4})/\d{2}/)  archive/$1 [L]